# solr - basic authentication

Tags: solr, solr8

(total beginner question alert!)
I am trying to set basic authentication on SOLR 8.3 (docker container: FROM solr:8.3)  following this [doc](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_3/basic-authentication-plugin.html):

I have added the /var/solr/data/security.json:

```
{
"authentication":{ 
   "blockUnknown": true, 
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}, 
   "realm":"My Solr users", 
   "forwardCredentials": false 
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}], 
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"} 
}}
```

when I try to change the default admin pass:

```
curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://10.x.x.x:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"solr" : "MyNewSuperSecurePass" }}'
```

I get the error :

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"No authentication plugin configured",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: First things first.. did you restart solr (after editing security.json and before calling the api) ? Also, you could begin with a basic security.json with minimal (unsecured) settings: eg. containing blockUnknown: false, no credentials, and the authorization block just mentioning its class. Then restart solr and use the api to set-user, set-user-role, and set-permission, and finish with set-property: blockUnknown: true.

Comment: Hi Eric, I did all that. I am posting an update as I've found the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that this behavior is only when running solr in container. Basically the security.json file must be put at container build time.
So I added to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM solr:8.3
ENV SOLR_USER="solr" \
    SOLR_GROUP="solr"
USER root
COPY --chown=solr:solr security/security.json /var/solr/data/security.json
USER $SOLR_USER
```

After this, the newly built container behaved as described in the documentations.